# Specifying OrderBys on RunReportRequest object using Google Analytics Data API (Beta)

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api

Using C#'s [Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta#package-manager), how do I set the `OrderBys` when creating a `RunReportRequest` object? The property has only `{ get; }` and no `set`. Perhaps this is not available in the Beta version?

```
var request = new RunReportRequest
{
    Property = $"properties/xxx",
    Metrics = { new Metric { Name = "screenpageviews" }, },
    Dimensions = { new Dimension { Name = "pagepath" }, },    
    DateRanges = { dateRange },
    // OrderBys
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [`RepeatedField`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/collections/repeated-field-t-) having an `Add()`, so you can use collection intializer syntax:

```
OrderBys = { new OrderBy(), }
```

Just as you do in the rest of your code (and please post code as text, not as screenshot).

You can also find code by [searching for "OrderBys" in their repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/search?q=OrderBys).

Comment: I've edited to include code as text. I never considered searching in their repo for examples. Thank you!